# I was wondering how I can save data which is inputted by the user via a form so as I can reload the data once the app is reopened

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store the data which is imputed by the user using a form and vanilla JS.

So when I reopen the the page any data pushed to the arrays are still visible when logged to the console.

I have done some research and understand using Json is the answer (I think).

I have done some research but everything I found seemed to use Node.js.

Any links or code would be very appreciated.

Note: I can post more of the code if needed, the code posted is the function which is executed once the form is submitted.

```
const formEl = document.getElementById('mainForm');
const comment = document.getElementById('comment');
formEl.onsubmit = function (e) {

    //Selecting the comment input on the form to pass to the 
    //comment waiters array.
    const comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;


    //Selecting the choosen index from the user food and which waiter orderd //it which waiter.
    //Selects the choosen food to pass to the addFood method in the waiter //class.
    const foodItemIndex = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;
    const foodItem = mainFood[foodItemIndex];


    //Selecting the waiter to push valid informaiton to.
    const waiterName = waitersEl.options[waitersEl.selectedIndex].value;
    const waiter = waiters.find(({name}) => name === waiterName);




    //Logic to check when submited if both feilds are true proceed.
    //The statements check to see which feild values have been entered
    //Then it call's the corresponding method from the waiter class and
    //pushes the value to the choosen array
    if (waiter && foodItem && comment) {
        waiter.addFood(foodItem)
        waiter.addComment(comment);
        console.log(waiters);
    }
    else if (waiter && comment) {
        waiter.addComment(comment);
        console.log(waiters);

    }
    else if (waiter && foodItem){    
        waiter.addFood(foodItem)
        console.log(waiters);
    }

    formEl.reset();
    return false; // prevents redirect/refresh



};
```

After the form has been submitted once:

```
0: Waiter
comment: ["This form has been submitted I will now close the window and when I reopen I will not be here"]
name: "Timo"
order: [Item]
total: 14
```

Now when I reopen:

```
0: Waiter
comment: []
name: "Timo"
order: []
total: 0
```

I want it so when I reopen the data is still inside the array.

Comment: What are you doing with the submitted form at the server?

Comment: @ Teemu, At the moment nothing, but I just want to be able to view past submitted data when I close and reopen chrome. (It is a ordering system for restaurants I am building for practice)

Comment: JSON is just a data transmission (and sometimes storage) format. There are others, such as XML. There's no requirement to use JSON here, although it is very popular and quite useful.

Comment: If you want to keep your data then you need some kind of persistent storage. You could use localstorage in your browser, which is fine if you always access your site from the same browser on the same device.

Comment: But if you want to share the data with other users and/or access your data from other devices then you will need some kind of server-side storage where you submit your form data to the server, which executes some code on the server, and then stores the data on the server (e.g. in a database). NodeJS is one such server side coding environment but you could use PHP or asp.net or java or several others, depending on your skillset and your operating system etc

Comment: @ ADyson, Thanks, this is what i am looking to do just store it in local storage as it is just for me to practice. When I was looking online everywhere I saw it was mentioning JSON.

Comment: Well that's probably because it's a very convenient format in which to store the data, but as well as the storage format you have to also choose the place to store it! If you don't know much about JSON then I'd recommend familiarising yourself, as it's very widely used, especially on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to use JavaScript, you can use either cookies or LocalStorage.

> LocalStorage is a type of web storage that allows Javascript websites
>   and apps to store and access data right in the browser with no
>   expiration date. This means the data stored in the browser will
>   persist even after the browser window has been closed.

LocalStorage works like this:

```
const person = {
    name: "Obaseki Nosa",
    location: "Lagos",
}

window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(person));
```

To retrieve the user key stored above:

```
window.localStorage.getItem('user');
```

This returns a string with value as;

"{“name":"Obaseki Nosa","location":"Lagos"}"

In order to get the values of everything in local storage, use:

```
Object.entries(localStorage)
```

To use this value, you would have convert it back to an object.

To do this, we make use of `JSON.parse()` method which converts a JSON string into a Javascript Object.

```
JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

However, if you want this to be an application and is not a form of homework, I would suggest saving and then getting back the data through the server (for example by using PHP and a MySQL database).

Comment: Thanks, this is just for practice for myself, I am doing a Computer Science course and going into second year where we will be learning more about PHP and MySQL. So maybe I will come back and use this again When I learn about PHP :)

Comment: That's really nice. If my answer helped you you can accept/upvote.

Comment: I will I have to pop out but will play around with the code when I am back, Thanks again

Comment: I have tried the code and it works, but when I refresh the page I still lose the data submitted when I log ' localstorage '  in DevTools?

Comment: You can access each value stored in localstorage with the code I suggested: window.localStorage.getItem('user');
In order to get all the items stored, use Object.entries(localStorage) (I edited my answer to contain it).